# Error in applying puppet modulepath?

Tags: puppet

Here is a snippet from my `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`

```
[main]
modulepath = /etc/puppet
```

When I try to use this path in a `init.pp` file I get an error

```
etc/puppet/modules/fangs/manifests# puppet apply init.pp
err: /Stage[main]//File[/tmp/test]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information
from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/fangs/files/sample.txt at /etc/puppet/modules/fangs/manifests/init.pp:7
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.05 seconds
```

Here is the content of my `init.pp` file

```
file { '/tmp/test':
    ensure => file,
    mode => '0777',
    source => "puppet:///modules/fangs/files/sample.txt",
#    source => "/etc/puppet/modules/fangs/files/sample.txt",
}
```

It runs correctly when I use the commented source `source => "/etc/puppet/modules/fangs/files/sample.txt",` with the full file path instead of the `puppet://` modulepath.

How can I fix my modulepath to make sure this works correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to customize the layout of your `modules` folder, there is no need to set `modulepath` in `/etc/puppet.conf`. If you leave it alone, the most common defaults are `/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules` (in the open source version) or `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules:/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules` (in Puppet Enterprise). If that is not your case, do set:

```
modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules
```

Shane Madden's information is correct, but it won't work with your current `modulepath` setting, because puppet will look for your modules directly under `/etc/puppet`. Unless you want to put them there (which you probably don't), you need to fix the `modulepath` and use:

```
source => "puppet:///modules/fangs/sample.txt",
```

as Shane suggested.

Answer (score 5):

When using a `puppet://` path, the "files" is implied.

Instead, try:

```
source => "puppet:///modules/fangs/sample.txt",
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about `files` automatically being added http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html#files